# How to replace words in string by regex pattern with exception

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a regex pattern:

`[a-zA-Z0-9]+.?(com|net)`

I use it to replace the words in strings with this function:

```
const formatString = (str) => {
   const regex = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9]+.?(com|net)","gi");
   return str.replace(regex, "*")
}
```

function execution examples:

```
formatString("google.com something else.net") // returns: "* something *"
formatString("google.com") // returns: "*"
formatString("something") // returns: "something"
```

but in some cases, I need to make an exception word so that it is not replaced.

Example:

exception word is `google` (or `google.com`)

`formatString("google.com something else.net") // should returns: "google.com something *"`

I tried to do it with `negative lookahead` using this pattern: `(?!google)[a-zA-Z0-9]+.?(com|net)`, but it does not work, it only ignores the first letter of the word.

Match information from https://regex101.com/

[image: match information from regex101 dot com]

Comment: the second parameter to string.replace can be a function for you to write custom logic.

Comment: any option to do it with regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
const regex = /\b(?!google\b)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(?:com|net)\b/gi;
```

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?!google\b)`  - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `google` as a whole word immediately to the right of the current position
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - one or more ASCII letters or digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?:com|net)` - a non-capturing group matching either `com` or `net`
- `\b` - a wor boundary.